# diazo ignores the JavaScript for web statistics

Tags: plone, diazo

I have a plone 4.2.1 site and I am using various diazo themes. I also use [Piwik](http://piwik.org/)  for web statistics. Unfortunately the javascript for web statistics is being utterly ignored when one of the diazo themes is installed. 
I have tried to edit the **rules.xml** file as suggested in https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/plone-users/VM4b51ergFA, but adding

```
<!-- Google Analytics JavaScript -->
<after theme-children="/html/body"
content="/html/body/div[@id='visual-portal-wrapper']/div/script" />
```

does not work for me.

Is there any other option which I can use to fix this issue?

Thanks, 
Julian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The viewlet plone.analytics is rendered in the footer viewlet manager:

```
<browser:viewlet
    name="plone.analytics"
    manager="plone.app.layout.viewlets.interfaces.IPortalFooter"
    class=".view.AnalyticsViewlet"
    permission="zope2.View"
    />
```

The snippet is rendered as it is, so you can identify your script tag in the way you want.

You shoud try

```
<script id="plone-analytics" ...>YOUR SCRIPT...</script>
```

And modify the rules.xml to put #plone-analytics in your footer

In Plone 4.2 at least the plone.analytics is not in the visual-portal-wrapper so the rule you try will not work.